# How to save admin options through ajax in a custom plugin (Wordpress)

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, plugins, admin

I'm learning how to create my custom plugin in Wordpress. I have it working right now and I'm very happy but I'm not able to save the options in my admin page using Ajax. Without Ajax I can save/load options in database from my custom plugin.

What's the easier way to do the same throught Ajax? The idea is to save it when I click a checkbox without click the submit button.

I've searching and trying for hours but I'm not able to do it so far.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Since WordPress doesn't provide an API for this you'd need to write your own AJAX script + PHP counterpart to fetch the values of these fields, validate them, then save them to the database. See: [AJAX in Plugins](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins).

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I've tried it following the documentation but I'm not able to do it. Do you know any tutorial to do it? thank you very much